# StreamReader issues

Tags: c#, exception, streamreader

i was trying to break my newly made servlet earlier and ended up breaking my own application, i kind of wish i hadn't bothered now!

```
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
String streamedXML = reader.ReadToEnd(); // 
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(streamedXML);
```

If i open up 10 windows or so, then rapidly request data from my servlets (this is the same 10 windows, returning the same data) then i get an xml exception being thrown;

```
Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed:
```

The thing is, if i run this one at a time, or with a large gap between requests then if completes fine. Is this because my streamreader **is being overwehlmed** by requests and starting new ones before others have finished? If so, is there a better way of writing this data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could try to fix this code or leave it to the experts and use a WebClient:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
     string streamedXML = client.DownloadString(sourceUrl);
     ...

}
```

And personally I would use XDocument instead of XmlDocument, but that depends.

Answer (score 2):

The StreamReader isn't overwhelmed. (It could only block or raise IO Exceptions / Out Of Memory exceptions)

However, it would seem that the server it is talking to is overwhelmed.

Find out with [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or in the server logs

Answer (score 1):

You could start by disposing of everything correctly and seeing if that helps:

```
using(response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using(reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    String streamedXML = reader.ReadToEnd(); // 
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(streamedXML);
}
```